# How to correctly write Rules with lookbehind in ANTLR

Tags: node.js, antlr, antlr4

I'm struggling with adding functionality to parse rule depending on previous symbols. To make it more clear, let me describe the case.

Currently I'm doing parsing VBLike script. There are some specific cases with line continuation symbol. Regulary, it looks like:

```
If Foo = "X" And _
    Bar = "Y" And _
    FooBar = "XY" Or _
    BarFoo = "YX" Then
    Bar = "far"
End If
// this one is short to make it more readable
```

However, there are some cases, when line continuation symbol consist not only from `_` symbol, but from `& _` combination. For such purpose, rule in `.g4` file was a bit modified:

```
LINE_CONTINUATION
    : WS* ((AMPERSAND WS)? '_') WS? '\r'? '\n' -> skip
    ;
```

And it seemed to be working fine, parsing cases like this:

```
If Foo = "X" And & _
    Bar = "Y" And & _
    FooBar = "XY" Or _
    BarFoo = "YX" Then
    Bar = "far"
End If
```

But, after we faced an issue when we had to parse scripts with line continuation AND String concationation (In VB we can concat strings with `&`). It looks like this:

```
If BasicChargeChkExst = Checked Then
    strTemp = "My Little" & _
              "Pony"
End If
```

The problem is that for current case `&` is considered to be a part of line continuation, as described now, but we should not include `&` in `LINE_CONTINUATION` if we had String Literal before `&`.

So, to sum up things, I should update `LINE_CONTINUATION` rule to make it work this way:

```
If Foo = "X" And _ ... // -> consider '_' as line continuation here

If Foo = "X" And & _ // consider '& _' as line continuation here because we have NOT a String literal before & (And, maybe any other keyword or something else)

str = "First part of string" & _ ... // should consider only '_' as line continuation because we have string before '&'
```

I understand, that such assumption are not pretty safe, but they'll cover most cases and I'll be fine even with that.

I just need to update `LINE_CONTINUATION` to resolve such cases. I'm working with node.js and antlr v4.7.0.  As I mentioned, currently it looks like:

```
LINE_CONTINUATION
    : WS* ((AMPERSAND WS)? '_') WS? '\r'? '\n' -> skip
    ;

...

STRINGLITERAL
    : '"' (~ ["\r\n] | '""')* '"'
    ;
```

Moreover, while "playing" with this rule, i tried to add alternative for it, but seems like it doesn't work the way I expect and understand. When I did:

```
LINE_CONTINUATION
    : WS* ((AMPERSAND WS)? '_') WS? '\r'? '\n' -> skip
    | ... Something here
    ;
```

I got error with message: `->command in lexer rule LINE_CONTINUATION must be last element of single outermost alt`. It would be nice if someine will explain me my mistake. We need to skip line continuation, but what is wrong with alternatives?

I really stucked on this one. Unfortunately, I do not have much time to dive into ANTLR deeply, so I'll appreciate any advise/code help/useful link or anything else that may help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I got your question right, `&` can be a part of either line continuation or string concatenation, which makes me think that the real purpose of `&` can be determined based on current context. And it seems to be a job for a parser, not a lexer. You can try to declare two tokens: `&` and `_` instead of `LINE_CONTINUATION` and then, in the parser, based on the current context (whether you concatenate strings or lines), determine the meaning of `&` token and handle it accordingly.

Comment: I reccomend not to deal with file level (or preprocessing) problems at parser level. Line continuation (or macro substitution and the like) are best handled in a preprocessing step. Create your own char input stream that deals with such things like concatinating lines and feed that to the parser. Makes processing a lot easier.